# PDO insert not adding records to database table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For some reason, the first SQL works (the UPDATE) but the second INSERT part does nothing and puts nothing into my new points table I just created. The Points table is simple with just these columns: ID, SID, WID, PID. Any idea why no data will populate it/no rows inserted?

```
if(isset($_POST ['yes'])){

// Get values from form 
$yes_WID = $_POST['yes'];

$yesupdate = "UPDATE writing SET approved = :approved, position = :position
WHERE WID = :WID";
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare($yesupdate);
$stmt2->bindParam(':WID', $yes_WID, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
$stmt2->bindParam(':approved', $e = Y, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt2->bindParam(':position', $row2[0]['position'], PDO::PARAM_INT);                                        
$stmt2->execute();


$storyauthor = $row[0]['stories.ID'];
$contpoint = 3;
$contauthor = $row2[0]['writing.ID'];

$yesupdate2 = "INSERT INTO points(ID, 
SID,
WID,
PID) VALUES(
:ID,
:SID,
:WID,
:PID)";
$stmt9 = $dbh->prepare($yesupdate2);
$stmt9->bindParam(':ID', $contauthor, PDO::PARAM_INT);      
$stmt9->bindParam(':SID', $the_SID, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
$stmt9->bindParam(':WID', $yes_WID, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
$stmt9->bindParam(':PID', $contpoint, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
$stmt9->execute();
```

Comment: You need to `setAttribute` on `$dbh`, do it before your ->prepare call.

Comment: Just tried that. Placed $dbh>setAttribute just before the $stm9 = $dbh-->prepare line as you said to do. Still got the same undefined error. Even if I get that to go, I'm guessing it won't show any error in the code though...

Comment: I just updated my code to show the entire code block. The first part of the code works but not the second. Maybe showing you this whole code block above might help you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No errors. The code simply won't add the data, but the computer sees nothing wrong with the code it seems. Maybe I can't do an update and an insert back to back like I am doing?

Comment: @jwalsh the `$yesupdate2` works fine.

Comment: @Phuti you mean it looks fine? I agree. It just won't seem to send data to that points table in mysql

Comment: @jwalsh it's working see http://testpdo.bugs3.com/file.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first statement there is an error in `$e = Y,`. `Y` must be defined as a constant or you have to put it in quotes. Also `'Y'` would be sufficient.

For the second insert statement we can only guess, because it is not possible to know what's in `$row` and `$row2`. To further debug, add this line before `$stmt9->execute();`:

```
echo "$contauthor, $the_SID, $yes_WID, $contpoint";
```

Check if it displays the expected values. Probably one of them is not defined, while the column in `points` doesn't allow null.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in and I like your thinking. Yes, I do see the expected values for the echo for the last 3 values...but not the first ($contauthor). It looks like:    , 76, 257, 3  but it should look like 1, 76, 257, 3.   As for the Y in the first part, that has always worked fine and continues to do so the way it is even with the Y in quotes. But I think you are on to something with the second part. Perhaps the first value not be captured is preventing the entire record from inserting? Is that possible?

Comment: You rock! When I set the first column to allow null, the record inserts. So now I know I just need to figure out how to capture the $contauthor and I'll be all set :) Thanks